# How can I get the day of the week with date given?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the day of the week (ex: Monday, Tuesday, etc.) with a random given date. This is my code:

```js
function dayOfWeek (date) {
  var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
  return day

  var day = date(i);
  document.write("get.day() : " + day.getDay());
}

var date1 = 11/19/2001;
console.log(dayOfWeek(date1));

var date2 =12/19/1969;
console.log(dayOfWeek(date2));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were quite a few things that were wrong with your code.

First is that you were incorrectly using a return statement. Any code after your return statement in the `dayOfWeek` function won't be run.

Also, `var date1 = 11/19/2001` is 100% not what you think it is. As it is now, it's two division operations, and not a string or date object. Notice in my code there are quotes surrounding the date value.

```js
function dayOfWeek (date) {
  const days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
  return days[date.getDay()];
}

var date1 = new Date('11/19/2001');
console.log(dayOfWeek(date1));

var date2 = new Date('12/19/1969');
console.log(dayOfWeek(date2));
```

You may want to look into [DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) and the `formatToParts` if you plan on allowing for other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine - But as noted from above, you have syntax errors and are actually using division (math) operators.

There's an easy way to get the date though.

From a library I built called [Date.js](https://github.com/Parking-Master/Date.js) - It allows you to get all dates using 1 function.

Here's a live example of Date.js:

```js
console.log("Current time:", date.js.time());

console.log("Current millisecond:", date.js.millisecond());

console.log("Current second:", date.js.second());

console.log("Current minute:", date.js.minute());

console.log("Current hour:", date.js.hour());

console.log("Current day:", date.js.day());

console.log("Current week:", date.js.week());

console.log("Current month:", date.js.month());

console.log("Current three-letter month:", date.js.tlmonth());

console.log("Current season:", date.js.season());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Parking-Master/Date.js@latest/date.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```